# Rails - Is the user the owner of the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What's the best way to check if the current object belongs to the current user?

I want to only allow the power of deletion to the owner, but I'm struggling to build a controller function to accomplish this.

```
  before_filter :signed_in_user,  only: [:create]
  before_filter :correct_user,    only: [:edit, :update,  :destroy]

...

def destroy
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  if @event.present?
    @event.destroy
  end
  redirect_to root_path
end
private
   def signed_in_user
     unless signed_in?
       store_location
       redirect_to signin_path, notice: "Please sign in."
     end
   end
   def correct_user
     @event = current_user.events.find_by_id(params[:id])
     rescue
       redirect_to root_path
   end
```

My current **def correct_user** allows any logged in user to make deletions.

Comment: I don't understand the question here. What is `correct_user` supposed to be doing? What exception could it possibly be rescuing there?

Comment: When you retrieve the event object, it's scoped to the user. Yes, anyone can delete (anyone logged in) but they can only delete what's scoped to them (events they own). Notice you grab the event by calling the method on current_user, and not the Event class.

Comment: @Mohamad I'm new to Rails (just finished the Rails Tutorial), can you explain more of how to correct the issue? Currently it tries to find an event that is owned by the current user. Wouldn't that return an error if the current_user doesn't own the event? Why does it still work?

Comment: @Mhsmith21 See my answer, and let me know if you still need me to clarify something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `correct_user` method is already doing what you need to do: fetching the event with `current_user.events.find`. You can just delete the event-finding code from your `destroy` method and it should work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

When I wrote my comment you had yet to added the `destroy` action code. Look carefully at the `correct_user` method:

```
   def correct_user
     @event = current_user.events.find_by_id(params[:id])
     rescue
       redirect_to root_path
   end
```

Right there you are retrieving the event and storing it in an instance variable. More so, you are retrieving the event through the `current_user`. So it's scoped to the `current_user`, and only events that are owned by the `current_user` are exposed.

```
 @event = current_user.events.find_by_id(params[:id])
```

Remember, `correct_user` is set in a `before_filter`, so it runs before the `destroy` action.

So, by the time the request gets to the `destroy` action, the event is already stored in an instance variable (`@event`). So there is already an event object for you to work with. You can reference that. There is no need to retrieve it again.

```
def destroy
  @event = Event.find(params[:id]) #<- This line is redundant (and dangerous in this case)
  ... # snip
end
```

Change the destroy method to this.

```
def destroy
  redirect_to root_path if @event.destroy
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just about to add similar functionality! You have to check if the current user is signed in, and if their ID = the user_id of the object.

Something like

```
  event = Event.find(params[:id])
  if event.user_id == current_user.id
    event.destroy
  else
    redirect_to :root, :notice => "You do not have permissions."
  end
```

Comment: usually it's better to use `#destroy` than `#delete`